# Flexible image buttons in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, haml

I'm working on a Rails application and using HAML for the views. I would like to use the "sliding doors" technique to create pretty buttons, which means I need to get HAML to generate something similar to the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span class="button">Button text</span></a>
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do that from the HAML reference or Google. Could you help please? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I need to use the link_to helper because I'm linking to a resource. When I try to pass a block into the method, I get an error: `undefined method 'stringify keys'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 = link_to invitation_path(invitation), :method=>:put, :class=>"button" do
   %span(class="button")
     Accept
```

Comment: can you clarify the html you want output.  I tried the code I put in my answer and it rendered identically to the html in your question.  Is there any information you're missing that could be causing the error?

Comment: Sure. I have an Invitation model. A user can accept or reject an invitation. In the view I have: link_to "Accept", invitation, :method => :put, :class => 'button accept'. I want to also render a span inside the link as I described in the question. If I add a block, I get the error I mentioned above. It seems very possible that what you suggested works perfectly, but fails when dealing with a resource.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I suggested a couple of tweaks to your answer as well. I'm not sure I care to find out what the cause is.

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as:

```
%a(href="#" class="button")
  %span(class="button") Button text
```

Or if you especially want it on one line without any whitespace you can do:

```
%a(href="#" class="button")<
  %span(class="button") Button text
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the link_to helper. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the question. I'll edit it appropriately.